# setjmp, longjump and stack reconstruction

Tags: c++, callstack, setjmp

Normally setjmp and longjmp does not care about call stack - instead functions are just preserving and restoring registers.

I would like to use setjmp and longjmp so that call stack would be preserved, and then restored at different executing context

```
EnableFeature( bool bEnable )
{
if( bEnable )
{
   if( setjmp( jmpBuf ) == 0 )
   {
        backup call stack 
   } else {
        return; //Playback backuped call stack + new call stack
   }
} else {
   restore saved call stack on top of current call stack
   modify jmpBuf so we will jump to new stack ending
   longjmp( jmpBuf )
}
```

Is this kind of approach possible - can someone code me a sample code for this ?

Why I believe by myself it's doable - is because of similar code snipet I have already coded / prototyped:

[Communication protocol and local loopback using setjmp / longjmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603384/communication-protocol-and-local-loopback-using-setjmp-longjmp)

There is two call stack running simultaneously - independently from each other.

But just to help you out with this task - I'll give you function for getting callstack for native and managed code:

```
//
//  Originated from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/diagnostic/
//
//  Similar to windows API function, captures N frames of current call stack.
//  Unlike windows API function, works with managed and native functions.
//
int CaptureStackBackTrace2(
    int FramesToSkip,                   //[in] frames to skip, 0 - capture everything.
    int nFrames,                        //[in] frames to capture.
    PVOID* BackTrace                    //[out] filled callstack with total size nFrames - FramesToSkip
)
{
#ifdef _WIN64
    CONTEXT ContextRecord;
    RtlCaptureContext( &ContextRecord );

    UINT iFrame;
    for( iFrame = 0; iFrame < (UINT)nFrames; iFrame++ )
    {
        DWORD64 ImageBase;
        PRUNTIME_FUNCTION pFunctionEntry = RtlLookupFunctionEntry( ContextRecord.Rip, &ImageBase, NULL );

        if( pFunctionEntry == NULL )
        {
            if( iFrame != -1 )
                iFrame--;           // Eat last as it's not valid.
            break;
        }

        PVOID HandlerData;
        DWORD64 EstablisherFrame;
        RtlVirtualUnwind( 0 /*UNW_FLAG_NHANDLER*/,
            ImageBase,
            ContextRecord.Rip,
            pFunctionEntry,
            &ContextRecord,
            &HandlerData,
            &EstablisherFrame,
            NULL );

        if( FramesToSkip > (int)iFrame )
            continue;

        BackTrace[iFrame - FramesToSkip] = (PVOID)ContextRecord.Rip;
    }
#else
    //
    //  This approach was taken from StackInfoManager.cpp / FillStackInfo
    //  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11221/Easy-Detection-of-Memory-Leaks
    //  - slightly simplified the function itself.
    //
    int regEBP;
    __asm mov regEBP, ebp;

    long *pFrame = (long*)regEBP;               // pointer to current function frame
    void* pNextInstruction;
    int iFrame = 0;

    //
    // Using __try/_catch is faster than using ReadProcessMemory or VirtualProtect.
    // We return whatever frames we have collected so far after exception was encountered.
    //
    __try {
        for( ; iFrame < nFrames; iFrame++ )
        {
            pNextInstruction = (void*)(*(pFrame + 1));

            if( !pNextInstruction )     // Last frame
                break;

            if( FramesToSkip > iFrame )
                continue;

            BackTrace[iFrame - FramesToSkip] = pNextInstruction;
            pFrame = (long*)(*pFrame);
        }
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
    }

#endif //_WIN64
    iFrame -= FramesToSkip;
    if( iFrame < 0 )
        iFrame = 0;

    return iFrame;
} //CaptureStackBackTrace2
```

I think it can be modified to obtain actual stack pointer (x64 - eSP and for x32 - there is a pointer already).

Comment: The `setjmp`/`longjmp` mechanism is quite delicate; if your code is to be remotely portable, you won't interfere with it.  If the `return` is executed, the `jmpBuf` will become invalid.  I'm not clear what you're thinking you might do to the `jmpBuf`, but it looks extremely dubious to me.  You should almost certainly rethink what you're doing altogether.  (Especially if you're using C++ — you should effectively never use `setjmp` or `longjmp` in C++.  You've got exceptions; use them.  They deal with the issues that `setjmp` and `longjmp` ignore, like resource management via destructors.)

Comment: You're looking for Boost's [stackful coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/spawn.html). Whatever you're doing yourself will eventually end up where boost is at, so you might as well call it a day and be done using something that works :)

Comment: Added more comments into question to the ones who don't believe it's possible. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Legally, `setjmp/longjmp` can only be used to jump "back" in the nested call sequence. Which means that it never needs to really "reconstruct" anything - at the moment when you execute the `longjmp` everything is still intact, right there in the stack. All you need to do is rollback the extra stuff accumulated on top of that between the moment of `setjmp` and the moment of `longjmp`.

`longjmp` automatically does a "shallow" rollback for you (i.e. it simply purges the raw bytes off the top of the stack without calling any destructors). So, if you wanted to do a proper "deep" rollback (like what exceptions do as they fly up the call hierarchy) you'd have to `setjmp` at each level that needs deep cleanup, "intercept" the jump, perform the cleanup manually and then `longjmp` further up the call hierarchy.

But this would basically be a manual implementation of "poor-man's exception handling". Why would you want to reimplement it manually? I'd understand if you wanted to do it in C code. But why in C++?

P.S. And yes, `setjmp/longjmp` are sometimes used in a non-standard way to implement co-routines in C, which does involve jumping "across" and a raw form of stack restoration. But this is non-standard. And in general case it would be much more painful to implement in C++ for the very same reasons that I mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a good use case for `setjmp` and `longjmp` in C++?  One of the points of exception handling is to ensure that destructors are executed properly, and `longjmp` bypasses that altogether.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I can sort of see a possibility for implementing coroutines in C++, where you want to quit executing the code in a scope, but want to maintain that scope in a form that it can be re-entered for continued execution later (i.e., as the coroutine yields, you do *not* want to execute the dtors for it or its calling sequence). That said, I doubt this can be implemented with (only) portable use of `setmmp`/`longjmp`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, but even so there are problems with, for example, mingws and MSVCs setjmp/longjmp implementations, so boost does not reply on setjmp/longjmp